# Use a FILE * in epoll

Tags: c, popen, file-descriptor

I am opening another process in my application using `popen` and parsing its output. I want to get notified as soon as the program has made any output. Currently all stuff in my program uses `epoll` for such actions. Now `popen` does return me a `FILE *` instead of a `fd`. Is it save to use the `fileno` function and put the resulting `fd` into `epoll`? If not, is there another way? I do not want the process to block, thats why I want the notifications.

Comment: I'd recommend against mixing buffered I/O (`FILE *`) and (e)poll. Personally I'd just write my own `popen_fd` that returns a descriptor you can `read` from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe, as long as you don't do any extra thing with the file descriptor without being careful it seems to be safe. One more thing, is that you probably want to mark the file descriptor as non-blocking too. So that you can `read()` without blocking and handle `EBUSY` or `EAGAIN` checking `errno`.

Comment: I agree with you that using `epoll()` on a file descriptor from a `FILE *` interface is safe - it just return the descriptor as being active.  But *mark the file descriptor as non-blocking*?  I don't think that's guaranteed to be safe if the actual reading is done via the `FILE *`-based stdio functions as mentioned in the question. Marking a `FILE *`'s underlying file descriptor non-blocking may cause serious problems as the library calls almost certainly aren't designed to use a non-blocking descriptor.